# How do I get android 14 to appear in device manager in visual studio

Tags: android, maui, visual-studio-2022

I am writing a .net MAUI app in Visual Studio 2022.

I have updated the sdk version to 34 but if I look in Android Device manager I can only see up to Android 13 and the latest pixel device in the list is the pixel 5. How do I get these updated to the latest

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio).
When you start the Studio you can find *Virtual Device Manager* under *More Actions* in the Welcome menu. From there you pick the Device you want and add Model and API Level.

To be clear. You manage all virtual devices, so what you see in Android Studio is the same devices you see in Visual Studio. If you just want to find Api34 you find it down on the last row saying unsupported, in the list when picking api level in Visual Studio Device Manager.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oe9tl.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a test on my visual studio(`Visual studio Community 2022(64-bit)`), at last a Pixel 5-API 34 emulator was created successfully.

The steps were as follows:

First enable the option of `Android SDK Platform 34` on `Android SDK Manager` Dialog.

[image]

Then, open the `Android Device Manager` Dialog, just as follows:

[image]

At last, I select the bottom option (`API 34`),then we just have to wait for the process of installation.